# Messed up Mount Options

Tags: release-loki, mount

I tried to to workaround elementary os not having the option of automount at startup by using the gnome-disks-utility and then it modified the /etc/fstab file. It was working fine, until after I installed some system updates using the AppCenter. the dock and wingpanel load after a very long time and the system shuts down slowly. 
So, I was wondering how to revert back to the default mounting procedure used by elementary os (without using /etc/fstab) , because when I deleted every line in fstab, the system wouldn't boot

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have a backup of your `/etc/fstab` files. Anyway, you should have at least one line in your `/etc/fstab` for your root file system:

```
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=239cd0e6-1516-47c0-945b-a2fc81b6f0499 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

If you do not know the UUID you can put the partition as well

```
/dev/sda1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

And you might want to swap or other partitions as well:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=fe12633c-3f88-21f0-9b26-29fff9eef210b none            swap    sw              0       0
```